# How to query data from Hidden csv files (starting with dot) on AWS S3 using Athena

Tags: android, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am uploading a hidden (name Starting with dot) comma separated values file to Amazon S3 and try to query data from Amazon Athena.I am not able to query the data for hidden files.

But, if we remove the dot(.) in name of file and try to query, then its working fine ,Athena is giving results.

Can anyone tell me is there any way i can work with hidden files?
or i will have to upload file with removed dot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into same issue and started exploring, but couldn't find a solution. Hence putting my findings here, hoping it may help others. This is more of information then an answer.

I tried further permutation combination, and I thought it might be issue with all `S3` `special` `characters` as per the official [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys), but its not the case, I have tested all the special characters
and it works for all of them fine except dot(.) and [underscore](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261332)(_). We could call it a bug.

**Issue with:-** `.` and `_`

e.g. filenames

{somepath}/_example_file1.data

{somepath}/.example_file2.data

**Works fine with:-** `!`, `-`,`*`,`'`,`(` and `)`

> Can anyone tell me is there any way i can work with hidden files? or I will have to upload file with removed dot(.)

Yes, you need to remove the dot(.) as workaround from file names to make it working.